# Computing conversion rate by counting TRUE/FALSE statements

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry if this sounds very basic; bear with me.

I need to determine the conversion rate of 3 ads, each representing a product; that would be subscription divided by the number of people who clicked the ad.

COLUMNS:

- person_id - unique identifier of the person
- date - date they were shown the ad
- ad_id - content of the ad: ad_1_product1, ad_2_product2, or ad_3_product3
- clicked (TRUE/FALSE) - clicked on the ad
- signed_up - (TRUE/FALSE) created an account
- subscribed (TRUE/FALSE) - started a paid    subscription

I set clicked, signed_up and subscribed as boolean.

MY CODE:

```
SELECT ad_id, (count(subscribed) / count(clicked)) as CR
FROM  videoadcampaign
WHERE subscribed = 'TRUE' AND clicked = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

Of course, the code above gives me a ratio of 1, because SQL is still counting the total and dividing by the same number because of those conditions.

I am totally stuck.

I will also need to calculate other KPIs for clicks and signed_up, so filtering those booleans and put them into a ratio is the core of what I need to do.

Is there a way I can tell SQL to compute CR = SUBS (TRUE) / SUBS (TRUE + FALSE) [or total count] and then filter by CLICK = TRUE?

Thank you tons for your help!

Comment: Column data types? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question is SQL. I am using SQL Lite and columns are set boolean for TRUE/FALSE, date for date, the rest to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your database, but the general notion would be:

```
SELECT ad_id,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN subscribed = 'TRUE' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN clicked = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ) as CR
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

In many databases, you can do something like this if the columns are integers (0 = false, 1 = true):

```
SELECT ad_id, SUM(subscribed) / SUM(clicked) as CR
FROM  videoadcampaign
WHERE clicked = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(subscribed) as CR
FROM  videoadcampaign
WHERE clicked = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Just so I understand the logic, the query tells SQL to assign "1" to count only if the condition is true, otherwise, it will count zero?

Comment: @DavideTaraborrelli . . . Well, `1.0` in case your database does integer division.