# Compute click-through rate by counting TRUE/FALSE statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, average

This is similar to my previous question here: [Computing conversion rate by counting TRUE/FALSE statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420062/computing-conversion-rate-by-counting-true-false-statements)

I thought it would still be useful to ask this in a separate question, because it uses a different logic.

I am using SQLite.

I need to determine the CTR of 3 ads, each representing a product; that would be subscription divided by the number of people who clicked the ad.

COLUMNS:

- person_id - unique identifier of the person
- date - date they were shown the ad
- ad_id - content of the ad: ad_1_product1, ad_2_product2, or ad_3_product3
- clicked (TRUE/FALSE) - clicked on the ad
- signed_up - (TRUE/FALSE) created an account
- subscribed (TRUE/FALSE) - started a paid    subscription

I set clicked, signed_up and subscribed as BOOLEAN, the rest is text.

MY CODE:

```
 SELECT ad_id,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN clicked = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
       COUNT(person_id) --as total impressions? not sure about this--
       ) AS CTR
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

I get 0 for CTR as a result.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your `clicked` doesn't really have values `TRUE` (either because there are any or because they're not spelled `TRUE` letter to letter). Try `CASE WHEN clicked LIKE '%TRUE%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `BOOLEAN` data type in SQLite as you can see here: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but you can define a column with that data type and you can store anything in it, even strings.

So, if you actually store in a column defined as `BOOLEAN` strings like `'FALSE'` and `'TRUE'` either you should have defined the data type as `TEXT` or better you should store in it values like `0` or `1` which represent `'FALSE'` or `'TRUE'` respectively and are better for performance in queries.

If you actually have string values in the column `clicked` you can get the result that you want by:

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(clicked = 'TRUE') AS CTR
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

The boolean expression `clicked = 'TRUE'` evaluates to `0` or `1` and `AVG()` returns the sum of all `1`s divided by the total number of rows.

If you have values like `0` or `1` in the column `clicked`(or their aliases `false` and `true` as identifiers and not string literals) then it is simpler:

```
SELECT ad_id, AVG(clicked) AS CTR
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

Comment: How do you query AVG impressions per day? Meaning doing an average on the total count of person_id, grouped by date?

Comment: @DavideTaraborrelli although I'm nut sure what you mean by *impression*, if you want the *total count of person_id, grouped by date* you should `group by date` and return select `count(*)`. If you want the overall average you need a 2nd level of aggregation and use AVG() on the results of the previous query.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(impressions) AS avg_impressions
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(person_id) as impressions
  FROM videoadcampaign
  GROUP BY date) date; ` I'm doing this but I get "avg_impression = 591.875; I can't break it down by date.

Comment: @DavideTaraborrelli what is the column date? Does it contain only the date or the time also? Anyway, questions are not asked in the comments section. You should ask this as a separate question where you provide sample data and expected results and explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does integer arithmetic.  You might check my answer to your previous question.  But you can do:

```
SELECT ad_id,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN clicked = 'TRUE' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) /
       COUNT(person_id) --as total impressions? not sure about this--
       ) AS CTR
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

Or if you have one row per `personid` and `personid` is not `NULL` then:

```
SELECT ad_id,
       AVG(CASE WHEN clicked = 'TRUE' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM  videoadcampaign
GROUP BY ad_id;
```